# How to trigger a reload on activity close?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

So I have an Activity containing a ViewPager, which contains a few Fragments, including one with a RecyclerView. You can click one of the items on the RecyclerView to edit all its details, which is done by launching a second Activity with editable fields specific to that item.

However let's say I change the name of the item. Now I press Save or the Back Button or whatever to close this Activity and go back to the first Activity. Since the name might be different now, the RecyclerView should also have the item's name updated.

But how do I detect this event? How do I basically do "when closing the second Activity, notify that the item has changed in the RecyclerView in the Fragment in the ViewPager of the first Activity"?

Can I use `onActivityResult`? If I am calling the second Activity from a Fragment using `startActivityForResult`, can I define `onActivityResult` in that same Fragment and then somehow use the Intent data to see, "okay, I need to refresh this position of the RecyclerView"?

Comment: yes, you can use onActivityResult for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use onActivityResult?

Yes. Here's how you can use it:

1. When an item is clicked in your `RecyclerView`, you keep track of the adapter position of the clicked item.
2. You start the second activity for result from within your fragment.

   ```
   // adapterPosition is the position of the clicked item
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
   intent.putExtras("adapter_position", adapterPosition);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   ```
3. In your `SecondActivity` set the adapterPosition as part of the result `Intent`. Handle `SecondActivity` result in your fragment.

In `SecondActivity`

```
    // adapterPosition is what you received from your fragment
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra("adapter_position", adapterPosition);
    // put other stuff you might need
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();
```

In fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            int adapterPosition = data.getIntExtra("adapter_position");
            // Update your RecyclerAdapter data. 
            // You will need to define this method in your RecyclerAdapter

            yourAdapter.notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
        }
        else {
            // Some error/cancel handling
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `startActivityForResult` from fragment to update your item and send it's current position.

```
intent.putExtra(POSITION_OF_RECYCLERVIEW,position);
```

and on Save button of `DetailActivity` call a method like setResult()

```
 private void setResult(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("UPDATE_POS", position);
        intent.putExtra("yourModelClassOrDataType",dataToUpdate);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When an item is clicked in your `RecyclerView`, keep track of the adapter position of the clicked item by placing the position into the intent and starting the second activity with `startActivityForResult(intent,1)`.

In the `fragment`:

```
    // adapterPosition is the position of the clicked item
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras("adapter_position", adapterPosition);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

You will be sending the adapterPosition and any new data you retrieved from the user while they were in the `SecondActivity` back to the fragment.  You send this by adding it to the result `Intent` as in the code below.

In the `SecondActivity`:

```
    // adapterPosition is what you received from your fragment
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra("adapter_position", adapterPosition);
    result.putExtra("new_item_name", itemName);
    // put other stuff you might need
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();
```

Now, in the `fragment`, you retrieve the adapterPosition and the new data from the `SecondActivity`.  Then manipulate the original list with the new data in a method I named below `doSomethingWithNewData`.  You will need to create this method.  Once your list is updated with the new data, then you pass this list to your adapter while calling a method from within your adapter that I called `updateAdapter`.  This is a method that you add to your adapter.

Back in the `fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(data != null){
                int adapterPosition = data.getIntExtra("adapter_position", -1); 
                String itemName = data.getStringExtra("new_item_name", -1);

                // Do something with the data passed back to fragment
                // ie. update the list attached to RecyclerView's adapter
                yourList = doSomethingWithNewData(adapterPosition, itemName);

                // add this method to your adapter passing new list
                yourAdapter.updateAdapter(yourList); 
            }    
        }
        else {
            // Some error/cancel handling
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this is your adapter.  This is where you add the `updateAdapter` method to the end of the adapter.  In `updateAdapter` you will be passing the new updated list and notifying that the data has changed with `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In `YourAdapter`:

```
private class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourViewHolder>{
    List<Object> yourList;

    public YourAdapter(List yourList){
        this.yourList = yourList;
    }

    public class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView text_1;
        TextView text_2;

        public NoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            text_1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            text_2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
        }

    }

    public YourAdapter.YourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        // inflate a layout to contain a single row from your list
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                 .inflate(R.layout.single_row_from_list, parent, false);
        NoteViewHolder yVH = new YourViewHolder(view);
        return yVH;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // set the texts using your modeled list
        holder.text_1.setText(yourList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.text_2.setText(yourList.get(position).getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // set item count to the size of your list
        return yourList.size();
    }

    // this is the method to add to the adapter
    public void updateAdapter(List<Object> yourList){
        this.yourList = yourList; // assign data passed in to the adapter list

        // notify that the data has changed
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```